# Why can I use void(), but not void{}?

Tags: c++, c++11, void, default-constructor

Consider the following code:

```
void foo() { return void(); }
void bar() { return void{}; }
```

`foo()` compiles, but `bar()` [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/59j6fa) (using GCC 8.2 and clang 7.0 on GodBolt).

Why?

Comment: Because it is invalid syntax.  Not sure why `void()` works.  Would you ever actually write code like this?

Comment: Related [How much existing C++ code would break if void was actually defined as `struct void {};`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53197340/1708801)

Comment: Templated code that returns `T{};`?

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, that makes sense (if it actually worked).

Comment: The related question that @ShafikYaghmour linked is a surprisingly complete answer to your question.

Comment: `void()` could be parsed as a C-style cast of an empty expression.  Is that valid?

Comment: +1 for Robert Harvey's comment that actually made me read the +1 link in Shafik Yaghmour's comment. Fun and informative with the lovely ingress  "_void is a bizarre wart in the C++ type system_".

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't see how. My question is about what I would consider a missing piece of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @John: Firstly, `void()` is a functional cast, not C-style cast. Secondly, uniform `void` in generic code is an important idiom in C++. It is surprising that someone finds this strange.

Comment: Clang sees a `CXXScalarValueInitExpr` in `return void();`, not a `CXXFunctionalCastExpr`. https://godbolt.org/z/gDlPj3 vs https://godbolt.org/z/--fPuE.

Comment: Direct dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46979441

Comment: @BaummitAugen it might answer it but it dupped badly because they dup it is linked to does not really answer this question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The question I linked of course does not answer the question, as it is an unanswered question. It surely is the same question though IMO. Now that that question's dupe target isn't great, I would agree.

Comment: One example more proving that uniform initialisation (as is now) was a ***big*** mistake added to the language...

Comment: @Aconcagua [Want some more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)?

Comment: @NathanOliver And I thought I had seen far enough already before, interesting enough, found my favourite sentence in: "Uniform initialization increases the mess."

Comment: @Aconcagua Unfortunately they decided not to break backwards compatibility.  I get why they decided that, but it has made something that should be easy a lot more difficult.  Throw in generic code and now you really have to pay attention.  Hopefully they'll figure out a way to fix it.  With the 3 year release cycle they are trying to maintain hopefully it wont be too long before it is fixed.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yeah, by 2026 C++ will probably be a great language, and by 2032 or so the libraries will have caught up as well :-)  ha-ha-only-serious...

Comment: @NathanOliver It's what in German would be called a 'Schnellschuss' - there are just too many issues with. One of my favourites: `std::vector<int> v{7}`; I *always* use parentheses: `v(7)` vs. `v({7})`, so everything clear. If `v{{7}}` had been mandatory for using initialiser lists (that one per se is a *great(!!!)* feature, by the way), and the other issues I discovered so far handled appropriately as well (please don't ask me now which ones, there *were* others, but I don't remember now...), then I'd need to start asking myself if I just was trying to preserve old habits. But as is *now*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` [is an incomplete type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#13).  Since it is an incomplete type the expression `void{}` is illegal.

`void()` however is granted an exception in [[expr.type.conv]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.type.conv#2)

> [...] If the type is cv void and the initializer
>   is (), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization. [...]

Which can be/is useful in generic code.

---

There is an [active issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2351) on this and the [current proposed wording for the C++20 draft](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2.sentence-2) is

> [...] Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization. [...]

Which will allow you to do `return void{};` if it is accepted.

Comment: I really like the second part of your answer!

Comment: @einpoklum Glad you liked it.  Hopefully compilers it will be adopted in and compilers get it added soon.

Comment: Alternatively you could say it is not an object which is what all the language in `[dcl.init.list]` uses. Also if the defect does not get accepted then we have to wait for "Regular Void"

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I just added an answer to the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53197340/1708801) earlier, explaining why I'm against `regular void` (at least the way the question presents it).